# How can we add icons to nodes of lightning-tree in Lightning Web Components

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am using the lightning-tree of Lightning Web Components.
Is there a way to add icons to tree nodes?

Here is my code...

```
<!-- Simple -->
    <div class="slds-p-around_medium lgc-bg">
        <lightning-tree items={items} header="Roles"></lightning-tree>
    </div>
```

**UPDATE**

Tried icons with tree-grid and got the icons visible. But I need different icons based on the type of node.
e.g. different icons for parent and child nodes.

[image]
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Use [`lightning-tree-grid`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-tree-grid/documentation) instead. This supports nested objects, like a `lightning-tree`, but also formatting, multiple columns, and icon features, as a `lightning-datatable`. A tree is meant to be more of a simple hierarchy display, like file folders or account hierarchy. If you want anything more complicated, use `lightning-tree-grid` instead.

Comment: can I get an example of appending icons in a tree-grid in front of all nodes?
I need icons based on the type of node.
e.g. folder must have folder icons and non-folder nodes must have different icons

Comment: @rrc1709 It's in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-tree-grid/documentation) under "Appending an Icon to Column Data".